# Find all X where X is in {a,b,c} and X != T.Y for Table T

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

Suppose you have a table T with primary key field ID and another field Y and that for some given values x1,x2, ...xn and i, you want to find all X in {x1,x2, ...xn} for which there is no row in T where T.Y = X and T.ID = i.  Seems like in order to do this I can create a temporary table TempT with a field Y and fill it with {x1, x2, ...xn}. Then I can do

```
select * from TempT left outer join T 
on(T.ID = i and T.Y = TempT.Y)
where T.ID is null
```

Is there a way to do this without a temporary table?

Comment: Are you using a mysql or sql server or oracle database?

Comment: Also, your question makes no sense without any sample data. X, Y,i...no clue what you are talking about.

Comment: Where do the `x`'s come from?  Are they passed in as a parameter along with `i`?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand.  (It looks to me like you're treating X as both a row and a column.)  But if I assume it's a row, then you should be able to use WHERE NOT EXISTS to get these results, I believe.  (At least you can do this with SQL Server.  I don't know about MySQL or Oracle.)

Comment: To clarify the x1,x2, xn are given as is i.  So for example the set X might just have one or two elements.

Comment: "x1,x2, xn are given as is i"? What do you mean? Is i just a string containing members in brackets? Does i literally just contain the string {x1,x2,x3,x4} or something of that sort?

Comment: x1,x2,...xn,i are all given.  i is a particular value of the ID field.  x1,x2, ...xn are values for the filed Y.

Answer (score 1):

In order to return the set remaining of {x1, x2, ..., xn} where you didn't find a T.Y, you're going to need to store it. You don't necessarily have to issue two statements, though, if that's an issue. See [values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) for SQL Server. I don't know if there's an equivalent Oracle function.

```
with xn as (
  select 
    x
  from
    ( VALUES ('x1'), ('x2'), ('x3'), ('x4'), ('x5') ) xn(X)
) 
select 
  * 
from 
  xn 
  left outer join T on
    T.Y = xn.X
    and T.id = i
where
  T.id is null
```